# Angular - NG201 error while running the server using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I get the below attached error - NG201 and it is not clear where the error is. I tried to find some sources and @Injectable and provideIn all set with the dataService which is the only servie i am having. I have built the app using ng build and run the server.js using node server.js. The login page is functioning fine, but when it comes to the quiz page i get this error. The error image is attached at the end.
**The dataservice class is:**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from 'user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataserviceService {

  headers!: HttpHeaders;
  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { 
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type','application/json');
  }

  getQuiz(): Observable<any>{
    console.log("flow 1 - from getQuiz() method in service");
    return this.http.get<any[]>('api/quiz');
  }

  checkLogin(user: User): Observable<boolean>{
    console.log('flow 5 - inside checkLogin() function in dataservice ' + " " + user);
    return this.http.post<boolean>('api/check-login', user);
  }

}
```

**It is injected properly into quizes.component.ts as:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Quiz } from '../quiz';
import { DataserviceService } from '../dataservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quizzes',
  templateUrl: './quizzes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quizzes.component.css'],
  providers: [DataserviceService],
})
export class QuizzesComponent implements OnInit {
  questions!:Quiz[];
  isSubmitted:boolean=false;
  selectedOption!:any;
  numberOfCorrectAnswers:number = 0;
  resultText!:string;
 isCorrect:boolean[] = [false];
  selectedQuestion!: Quiz;
  answered:boolean[] = [false];
  answerResult:string[] = [''];
  viewResult:boolean = false;
  constructor(private ds:DataserviceService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ds.getQuiz().subscribe({
      next: data=>this.questions = data
    })
   
  }

  getSelectedOption(questionIndex: number, question:Quiz){
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    this.selectedQuestion = question; 
    let result = this.isCorrectAnswer(questionIndex);
    this.answered[questionIndex] = true;

    if(result){      
      this.resultText = "Answer is correct";    
      this.answerResult[questionIndex]  = this.resultText;
      this.isCorrect[questionIndex] = true;

    }
    else{
      this.resultText = "Answer is wrong";            
      this.answerResult[questionIndex]  = this.resultText;
      this.isCorrect[questionIndex]=false;
    } 
    
    
  }

  isCorrectAnswer(questionIndex:number) {  
    const isCorrect = this.questions[questionIndex].answer === this.selectedOption;
  
    if (isCorrect) {
      this.numberOfCorrectAnswers++;
    }
    return isCorrect;
  }

  isCorrect1(i:number){
    return this.isCorrect[i];
  }

  isAnswered(i:number){
    return this.answered[i];
  }

  getResult(){
    this.viewResult = true;
  }

}
```

**The quizzes HTML is:**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index" class="card md-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ question.question }}</h5>
      </div>
      <div *ngFor="let choice of question.choices; let j = index" class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{j}}" [(ngModel)] ="selectedOption"/>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="option{{j}}">
          {{ choice }}
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getSelectedOption(i,question)" [disabled] = "selectedQuestion===question || isAnswered(i)">Check Answer</button>
      <div *ngIf="selectedQuestion===question || isAnswered(i)">
          <div [ngClass] = "isCorrect1(i)?'correct':'wrong'">{{answerResult[i]}}</div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-5 mb-3" (click)="getResult()" >Check Result</button>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: First, you should be running your app in dev Mode. You would have a more explicit error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i forgot to import FormsModule along with ReactiveFormsModule in app.module that lead to this error as i was using [(ngModel)] which requires FormsModule.